# How to group documents by month?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of transaction data in mongodb, like this:

```
[
   {timestamp: ISODate("2015-11-10T11:33:41.075Z"), nominal: 25.121},
   {timestamp: ISODate("2015-11-22T11:33:41.075Z"), nominal: 25.121},
   {timestamp: ISODate("2015-11-23T11:33:41.075Z"), nominal: 26.121},
   {timestamp: ISODate("2015-12-03T11:33:41.075Z"), nominal: 30.121},
]
```

How can I use mongodb's `aggregate` to calculate my total transaction each month?

I tried:

```
db.getCollection('transaction').aggregate([
  { $group: {_id: "$timestamp", total: {$sum: "$nominal"} } }
])
```

But it failed since I use `timestamp` instead of `month`. I don't want to add another field for `month` to transaction data. I think about a custom made function for $group pipeline that returns month value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a preliminary [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you use the [`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) operator to return the "month".

```js
 db.transaction.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "nominal": 1, 
        "month": { "$month": "$timestamp" }
    }}, 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$month", 
        "total": { "$sum": "$nominal" }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : 12, "total" : 30.121 }
{ "_id" : 11, "total" : 76.363 }
```

Comment: This will work well only if you have only less than 12 months of history in the database. A correct implementation should return year-month data.

Comment: @sorin from mongodb 3.0+ you can use $dateToString instead of $month and you can pass on a format (ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

Comment: Or if you are below 3.0 you can hack your way to a concatenated version of the date. You need 2 project stages, one to format $month and $year separately. Then another stage to use $concat and concat the 2 new fields. Don't forget to use substr on the year and month, since you can't concat integers.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to group per `year-month` (to avoid months from different years to be grouped together), you can use [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/):

```
// { timestamp: ISODate("2015-11-10T11:33:41.075Z"), nominal: 25.121 }
// { timestamp: ISODate("2015-11-22T11:33:41.075Z"), nominal: 25.121 }
// { timestamp: ISODate("2015-11-23T11:33:41.075Z"), nominal: 26.121 }
// { timestamp: ISODate("2015-12-03T11:33:41.075Z"), nominal: 30.121 }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: { $dateToString: { date: "$timestamp", format: "%Y-%m" } },
    total: { $sum: "$nominal" }
  }}
])
// { _id: "2015-12", total: 30.121 }
// { _id: "2015-11", total: 76.363 }
```